# microsoft graph createreply wrong timezone

Tags: timezone, microsoft-graph-api, angular5

In our Angular 5 application, we are using Microsoft Graph to retrieve mail messages from a mailbox and then send a reply. For creating the reply, we use the REST API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{message ID}/createReply
```

This creates a reply with a timezone that is UTC, but we expect it to be GMT+1. For example, in the mail body it says:

**From:** Melissa van Dijk 
**Sent:** Friday, February 23, 2018 9:51:49 AM    (wrong timestamp)
**To:** Melissa van Dijk
**Subject:** Meet for lunch?

We checked the settings in our Office 365 mail account and there it is specified that our local timezone is GMT+1 (Brussels, Amsterdam...). 
(When replying via Outlook webmail, we get a correct timestamp).

Is this a bug or do we have to correct this timestamp ourselves? Or do we need to pass the timezone with the REST call somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can adjust the human-formatted timestamps in the HTML message body, but you can certainly use the ISO 8601 formatted timestamps in the other fields in the JSON of the response.  For example, you'll find:

```
{
  ...
  "sentDateTime": "2018-02-23T09:51:49Z",
  ...
}
```

While this is also in UTC (denoted by the `Z`), you can easily parse it by using a JavaScript `Date` object, or Angular's own datetime functions, or your favorite time library such as Luxon, Moment, or Date-fns.  From there, displaying it in local time is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the current behaviour, as discussed here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/520090/sent-time-is-in-utc-when-using-createreply

However, you can override it using Prefer header.

```
.header('Prefer', 'outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"')
```

You can use the below endpoint to get the timezone of a mailbox at runtime.

```
/users/<<mailbox>>/mailboxSettings/timeZone
```